# What would be a better solution for storing data in a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

Could you please give me a piece of advice?

Context:
I have a Django project in which each user stores many different variables linked to his profile. I created a model called Snapshot, that has a foreign key of user. Single user can have multiple Snapshots linked to his User instance, but only the latest one (by its ID, pk) is editable. Any other ones might be used to revert to past setup only.

Typical use case:
User modifies his setup stored in his latest Snapshot using API endpoints. Each function that an endpoint call has to query the latest Snapshot owned by user that called the function. Then it modifies some of the variables in the Snapshot and saves it. Once everything's done user approves the setup and the Snapshot is being duplicated. Now the new instance becomes the latest.

Question:
Is it a good idea to query the latest Snapshot this many times in each function? Wouldn't it be a good idea to link the latest Snapshot one-to-one with User, so that it's always available as User.latest_snapshot? This latest_snapshot would be automatically re-linked to User once user approves setup, thus creating a new Snapshot.

Example code:

models.py:

```
class Snapshot(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='snapshots', ... )
    var_1 = models.IntegerField( ... )
    ...
    van_n = models.IntegerField( ... )
```

views.py:

```
class ExampleEndpoint(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        first_function(request.user)
        ...
        nth_function(request.user)

        return Response({ ... })
```

controller.py:

```
def first_function(user)
    current_snapshot = user.snapshots.last() # <= I'm asking about this query - Is this okay to query in this way in every single function of the controller?
    # do many things with snapshot variables here
    current_snapshot.save()
```

Comment: I don't think in this case breaking normalization rules will gave any improvements. It will be the same queries count in normalized way and with additional one to one relation. As far as I know, but I am not db expert

Comment: Nobody will give you solution without a code example. Please provide one i will be happy to help.

Comment: I added a brief example. Maybe it will help to understand the question better.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good idea to query the latest Snapshot this many times in each function?

You don't have to query the last instance in each function you can just query it once in your endpoint and pass the instance to each function.

> Wouldn't it be a good idea to link the latest Snapshot one-to-one with
> User, so that it's always available as User.latest_snapshot?

It depends on your requirement if you don't need to keep a history of snapshot  then one to one relation is fine otherwise you need to keep it foreign key relation. But then also if you keep it foreign key you can keep a limited history say latest 10 changes or more again depends on your requirement.

**Edit:**

I would suggest to keep only one relation that is foreign key with that you can get both latests and all. No need to add One to One Field as then you don't have to maintain two relations and overengineer things.

You can get the latest snapshot using [latest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#latest) by giving id field of your snapshot model by default id field is indexed so will be much faster [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/optimization/#retrieve-individual-objects-using-a-unique-indexed-column)

Comment: One to one relation will still keep the full history here. I will have access to the latest Snapshot by User.latest_snapshot which is one to one relation and in the same time full history available by using User.snapshots. Its just a matter of what I was asking - is it any better than making user.snapshots.last() query over and over?

Comment: So you mean you have two different relationships one foreign and one one to one using same model right ? But you didn't mention it before neither in code nor in post.

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly that. So is it a good idea?

Comment: Better idea is to just have one relation i.e a foreign key. Because one having two relationships is redundant and second it is more work as you have to maintain two relationships when you can use only one.

Comment: If it's beneficial in terms of speed I think it's worth it. I'd update the relation automatically whenever new Snapshot is created